# Save data string for the next run of wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have A function that automatically uses A printer name and prints data without opening printer Dialog.
I want to be able to keep the printer name as A resource or A file in case the printer is not exist anymore or it's name has been modified, and to keep the updated name for the next run of the application

my question is:
What is the best practice doing that?

I'm currently keep the printer name as A const string 'PRINTER_NAME'
The code :

```
 private void print_DefaultNum_Print(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isSent_ok = true;
        // device-dependent string, need a FormFeed?
        string s = "!U1 getvar " + "device.unique_id";
        // Allow the user to select a printer.
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PRINTER_NAME;

        for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_NUM_COPIES && isSent_ok; i++)// send # of copies
        {
            isSent_ok = RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, deviceName);
            if (isSent_ok == false)
            {

                if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
                {

                    // Send a printer-specific to the printer.
                    for (int j = 0; j < pd.PrinterSettings.Copies; j++)// send # of copies
                        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, deviceName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Take a look at [Application Settings and User Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF fires an event when the application is exiting.  I would handle this event, and in that code, I would write any persisted data to a file.  First, in App.xaml, start typing "Exit=" in your Application tag.  Visual Studio should recommend adding a new event handler - click that option so it wires it up for you.  Your app.xaml will look something like:

```
<Application x:Class="MyWpfApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyWpfApplication.ViewModel"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Exit="Application_Exit"
             mc:Ignorable="d ignore">


</Application>
```

Now go to your app.xaml.cs file and you should see an empty method called Application_Exit.  Add code to save the string to a file:

```
private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    string applicationPath = Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); // the directory that your program is installed in
    string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, "printini.txt"); // add a file name to this path.  This is your full file path.
    File.WriteAllText(saveFilePath, PRINTER_NAME);
}
```

To load it, you can use the same process to handle the Startup event - your code for the empty method it wires up would look like this:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    string applicationPath = Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); // the directory that your program is installed in
    string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, "printini.txt"); // add a file name to this path.  This is your full file path.

    if (File.Exists(saveFilePath))
    {
        PRINTER_NAME = File.ReadAllText(saveFilePath);
    }
    else
    {
        // prompt the user for a printer...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this solution